# CKEditor: Placeholder with pre-defined values

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, ckeditor, placeholder

This is a regular script to load the placeholder facility into your CKEditor:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title></title>
    <!-- CK Editor -->
    <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.4.7/standard-all/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea id="email_message_new"></textarea>
<script language="javascript">
 var ck_edit_new = CKEDITOR.replace('email_message_new', {
  extraPlugins: 'placeholder',
  height: 220
 });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Second: I am trying to load pre-defined values into CKEditor's Placeholder modal. It should look somehow like this [Screenshot](http://s1.ckeditor.com/sites/default/files/uploads/Untitled-2.jpg) which was asked here (http://ckeditor.com/forums/CKEditor-4-Add-Ons/Modifying-the-placeholder-plugin)

Third: 
CKEditor Docs says about the Placeholder customization:

> You could, for example, customize the dialog window to show a
>   drop-down list with pre-defined options that can be selected to fill
>   the placeholder.

Unfortunately nothing can be found in their reference/docs. I would like to know, what would be a "no-hack" (for instance by editing placeholder/plugin/config.js) approach to get a dropdown menu into the Placeholder Modal window.

Any help is appreciated
Thanks

Comment: What have you tried already? The only code you have is a code that initialises an editor. I advise you to read official guides like [CKEditor plugin SDK](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_intro) and [CKEditor Widgets SDK](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/widget_sdk_intro) after which you should not have any problems in changing the placeholder plugins according to your needs.

Comment: Yes, the code provided initializes an instance including the Placeholder plugin. I was just wondering, if it is mentioned on the CKEditor docs ("...drop-down list with pre-defined options..." see [link](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_placeholder)) then either because it is a common thing to do or they forgot to add some sample snippet? I guess I will have to go through the dev docs. Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I'm running into the same issue, they indicate that it's possible but there's no documentation on how to do this...

Comment: Just added the solution I found below.

Answer (score 4):

With CKEditor 4 you can extend the `placeholder` plugin without core changes or custom addons. The code below will change the placeholder input to a select like your screenshot:

```
CKEDITOR.on('dialogDefinition', function(event) {
  if ('placeholder' == event.data.name) {
    var input = event.data.definition.getContents('info').get('name');
    input.type = 'select';
    input.items = [ ['Company'], ['Email'], ['First Name'], ['Last Name'] ];
    input.setup = function() {
      this.setValue('Company');
    };
  }
});
```

Source: http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog.definition.select

Comment: Do you know how to submit input.type = 'radio' values on onClick event? Your example works fine if I try submit values on commit event which is activated by clicking OK button but it doesn't work if I use onClick event.

Comment: This should be asked as a new question, but I can help you. You could monitor clicks on the radios and simulate a click on the OK button. If you are using jQuery, add the following inside the input.setup function: `$('.cke_dialog_ui_radio_input').on('click', function(){ $('.cke_dialog_ui_button_ok')[0].click(); });`

Comment: would you know how to change the text "Placeholder Properties"?

Answer (score 1):

know that this thread is a bit old, but I had the same need and created a plugin to do exactly what you're after.  It's not using Angular but it's flexible enough to be configured via Angular.

I've created the "Placeholder Tokens From Dropdown" plugin for CKEditor. It works in much the same way as the strinsert plugin that Simon is talking about, although with more flexibility.

You can pass in a config including a 'format' (in case you don't want to use the pleceholder plugins format). It uses the placeholder format by default [[something]], but can use anything else (For example {{something}}).

The placeholder tokens can be passed in as a JavaScript array via the config. The plugin will do the rest for you.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/placeholder_select

Answer (score 0):

The following blog post by Zachary Olson explains how to do it: https://zolson.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/ckeditor-placeholder-select/

You basically edit the file `placholder/dialog/placeholder.js` and change the type from text to select and then add the items you want as shown in the following code:

```
type : 'select',
items : [ [ 'meetingTime' ], [ 'meetingLocation' ] ],
'default' : 'meetingTime',
```

That's the gist of it, but you can get more details on [his blog post](https://zolson.wordpress.com/2011/04/19/ckeditor-placeholder-select/)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Stephane answers, I arrived to a slightly different solution. 
The basic idea I adopted is to wait until the editor object exist and then re-register the dialog. Acting this way I do not risk to have my changes overwritten when the plugin code is updated.

I implemented this idea working with angular.js . In my project I borrowed a co-worker module where the the ckeditor was included this way in the modulename-index.html:

```
<div ckeditor="editorOptions" ng-model="obj.editorModel" ready="onReady()" />
```

Therefore when i hacked (as in "hack'n'slash", not as in "clever hacking") i defined the onReady() function by dumping in the CHECKEDITOR.dialog.add() call contained in the plugin placeholder.js and then changed the element type and added the array of items.